# Why does this <div> element - which was floating - suddenly "sink" when I give it a width?

Tags: html, css

I have this simple snippet of HTML which defines a `div.main_col` element, which gets the property `float: left;`.
I thought assigning `float: left;` to this `div.main_col` would cause elements defined after it to sit up alongside it, even if those subsequent elements were `display: block` - thats the point of `float` right?
<sub>(of course assuming there was still enough room in the viewport for the new elements to sit alongside `div.main_col` )</sub>
Here is my code

```
<div class="main_col">
            <h1>Leela's gonna kill me.</h1>
            <p>Good news, everyone! There's a report on TV with some very bad news! I'm
            sure those windmills will keep them cool. Ah, the 'Breakfast Club'
        soundtrack! I can't wait til I'm old enough to feel ways about stuff!</p>
</div>
<div class="floatee">
  <h3>float me</h3>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/80" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main_col {
   width: 450px;
   float: left;
}
.floatee {
    /*   width: 100px; */
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Ad sure enough, as you can see from [this codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PzBgmO?editors=1100) the second div floats alongside the first.
However if I simply set the width of the `div.floatee` element to `100px` -  it suddenly stops floating and now 'sinks' to the bottom of the document.
View this here at: [same
codepen as above but with ".floatee" `width: 100px`](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NABmdr?editors=1100).
Even though there is plenty of room for the `div.floatee` element to sit alongside it still sinks.

Why does the element `<div class="floatee">` suddenly sink when I set a width on it?
Note: I understand I could get `<div class="floatee">` to float again by removing the width or setting its own style to float, but I want to understand what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought assigning float: left; to this div.main_col would cause
>   elements defined after it to sit up alongside it, even if those
>   subsequent elements were display: block

That's your misunderstanding. The floatee div doesn't sit alongside it, it overlaps it. The line boxes inside the floatee div avoid the floated main_col, not the div itself.

So when the floatee div has a width less than the width of main_col, there's no space inside the floatee div for the line boxes to go which would avoid the main_div until the first line box can be placed below the main_col div. Hence the height of the floatee div increases and its content goes below main_col.

Comment: That's the correct answer, for more information see the specs on block formatting context: http://w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting

Comment: ok, I see now, once you understand that the boxes are overlapping, and that the width on the floatee's box is actually - in normal flow -and therefore reducing its width basically squeezes the line boxes out, it its pretty obvious. the link Paul provided was helpful, https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/ was useful too. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check below example of codes in `example-1` i.e. when you define just `width` without any `value assign` to it then by `default` it take `width` of `100% view-port width`, but in `example-2` when you define or assign value to your `width` it `shrinks` to assign `width`.

**Example - 1**

```
<div>
<p>
Good news, everyone! There's a report on TV with some very bad news! I'm
            sure those windmills will keep them cool. Ah, the 'Breakfast Club'
        soundtrack! I can't wait til I'm old enough to feel ways about stuff!
</p>
</div>
div{
  background:#f22;
}
```

**Example - 2**

```
div{
    width:100px;
    background:#f22;
} 

<div>
<p>
Good news, everyone! There's a report on TV with some very bad news! I'm
            sure those windmills will keep them cool. Ah, the 'Breakfast Club'
        soundtrack! I can't wait til I'm old enough to feel ways about stuff!
</p>
</div>
```